# Is there a way to make an excel sheet live editable by multiple people on sharepoint?

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I am trying to make a workbook that automatically updates when it is saved or completely live, to be used almost like a google doc sheet but it needs to be on excel. But it needs to be viewed or edited by multiple people at the same time. It needs to be done on share point. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your version of SharePoint. With SharePoint 365, which is online, files can be edited in Excel Online, which allows co-authoring by multiple people.

For on-premises farms you can use the Excel Web App, which also allows simultaneous editing by multiple people.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Excel-Web-App-d2838b0e-ee37-467f-a4c7-38d2bd81bfd1